# Identifying lines that enter a polygon but don't cross it entirely

Tags: polygon, line, spatial-join, predicates, spatial-predicates

I need a method to differentiate the two scenarios below where a line only enters a polygon and another where a line enters and leaves the polygon, crossing it entirely.

[image: Want to differentiate the two on GIS]

On QGIS I tried using the **join attributes by location** function with both the **intersect** and **crosses** predicates. However, both instances are selected in either case.

Comment: Compute the intersection points between the line and the polygon ring and check if the number is even or odd?

Comment: @user30184 I don't think that would work if the line is tangent to the polygon, although it's unclear what the desired behavior is in that case.

Answer (score 5):

The LineString boundary are both start and end point. At least one of them must intersect with the interior of the Polygon (you can include an OR condition if you want to allow interior-interior and boundary-boundary intersection). The [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) pattern for your case is `'***T*****'`.

Run the [Execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#execute-sql) process with the following query:

```sql
SELECT lines.id AS lineid, polygons.id AS polygonid, lines.geometry AS geom
FROM lines
INNER JOIN polygons
ON ST_Relate( lines.geometry, polygons.geometry, '***T*****');
```

You don't need to worry about all other parameters in the Execute SQL dialog. But you need to change the name of the layers and fields to be joined.

Comment: I believe that the meaning was that exactly one end of the line should intersect with the interior. Does this DE-9IM handle also that "and not within" rule?

Comment: It could be limited to the fact that the boundary of the lines must intersect with the interior and exterior (the line starts outside but ends inside) of the polygons with the pattern: `'***T*T***'`. It is not strictly a not-within relationship (a line that starts inside, leaves, and ends inside the polygon again would be excluded from the selection even though it is not within the polygon). If it is necessary to include or exclude these cases, of course it is possible, but it is not clear in the question how to decide on them since they are not included in the scenarios to be differentiated.